# No slow motion effect in exported from camera roll video on iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, slowmotion

I'm developing app that works with video. It makes short movies from recorded or exported from camera roll videos. I need help with some unexpected behavior.

When I export video recorded with apple slow motion effect - such effect is lost in video in my app.

This's reproduced on iPhone 6 and 6+ and I assume on iPhone 5s too. On iPhone 5s/6/6+ Simulator, everything is ok. To export video I use iOS SDK **ALAssetsLibrary** API, code:

```
NSMutableArray* allVideos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[self.assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes: ALAssetsGroupAll
                                 usingBlock: ^(ALAssetsGroup* group, BOOL* stop1){

                                     if (group) {
                                         [group setAssetsFilter: [ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
                                         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock: ^(ALAsset* asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL* stop2){

                                             if (asset) {
                                                [allVideos addObject: asset];
                                             }
                                         }];
                                     }
                                     else {
                                         //sort by last shooted video
                                         self.view.videoAssetRepresentations = [allVideos sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult (ALAsset* obj1, ALAsset* obj2) {
                                             return [[obj1 valueForProperty: ALAssetPropertyDate] timeIntervalSince1970] < [[obj2 valueForProperty: ALAssetPropertyDate] timeIntervalSince1970];
                                         }];
                                     }
                            }
                               failureBlock: ^(NSError* error){
                                   DbgLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
                               }];
```

To play exported video I use **AVPlayer** instance.

Please help me - how can I solve my problem?

PS - Instagram app can do this, tested on iPhone 6. Exported video contains slow motion effect inside Instagram app.

Comment: Sorry, I left the video world awhile back. But I'm pretty sure that slow mo worked for us back then. My comment was more just to get you to show us some code, at least then somebody will have a chance to help.

Comment: Solved this issue with the use of new iOS 8 **Photos** framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1025773#1025773

It seems that you cannot do this with the `ALAssetsLibrary`. However, with the new **Photos framework** for iOS 8+ you can use `PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate`

Comment: New iOS 8 **Photos** framework did the trick. 
Exported video contains slow motion effect.

Comment: There's a typo in that variable name. It's actually "PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate"